# Do I have to close Word Interop Application?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm using the following code:

```
using MSWord = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

.
.
.

MSWord.Application wordApp = new MSWord.Application();

MSWord.Document wordDoc = new MSWord.Document();

wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(Template: oTemplatePath);

//do something with the Document... replace fields and so on...

wordApp.Visible = true;
```

the function then exits and my app is closing down, for example. 
Now the user can edit the open document, and save it or just close it.

Do I have to close the Application-Object (in terms of COM-Objects and so on) programmatically??? Or does this the Garbage collector?

Comment: I had a different situation than you (I was reading an Excel file), but in my case, I needed to close the workbooks I was working with and quit the application (in code) otherwise the EXCEL.EXE process would stay open in the Task Manager, even after I closed the document I was reading (by closing Excel).

Comment: Henrik, please pay attention to the comments at DJ KRAZE answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to correctly close / dispose COM Objects when using Microsoft.Interop
you would want to use this method

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject( "Replace with your ComObject Here");
```

so for example if I have created an object named wordApp I would declare it like this and dispose it like the following

```
MSWord.Application wordApp = new MSWord.Application();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
```

This can give you an example of how to use ReleaseComObject
[Marshal.ReleaseComObject Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx)

Comment: Isn't it safer to use Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(...) if you don't intend to use the object anymore?

Comment: Except that he's not dealing with COM objects, because Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace is managed, and handles the Word COM interfaces automatically. So wordApp is automatically collected by GAC at the end of the method/application.

Comment: LMB if I am not mistaken Microsoft Interop which was better known as OleAutomation does make use and or is COM Interop.. how else would he be able to get MSWord Application to work..?

Comment: Sure Sir, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word DO USES COM Interop. It does it so that YOU don't have to deal with the COM objects. It's called abstraction layer. The single only purpose of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word is to prevent you form dealing with the complexities of OLEAutomation. As you can read in MSDN "The types and members of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace provide support for interoperability between the COM object model of Microsoft Word 2010 and managed applications that automate Word"

Comment: Ok many thanks to everybody! I tested the suggestions and found out that when I use my code without releasing the com-object and want to shutdown windows, it is asking my for saving open (but not visible) documents. When I use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);  then windows is not asking me and everything is fine. So I think I can release the com-Object even if the real Word-Document will be still open and editable for the user. I hope I have not missed something, but it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

You're ok. When you call  `new MSWord.Application();` a new Ms-Word process starts and manages the Document.

You don't have to worry. If you display the document to the user, when he closes the document all will be done.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Can you please undo the mess you did in this question?

Comment: What are you talking about..LMB.. All I stated was that you were not totally correct with your response... I am interested in knowing if the solution even helped the OP